# 403 Forbidden error on Ubuntu + Apache2 + Passenger Rails server

Tags: apache-2.4, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04, phusion-passenger

Just started a server on Linode, with Ubuntu 14, Apache and Passenger. Deployed a rails app with capistrano, configured and enabled the site, but it launchs a 403 error when attempting to access:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at [url] Port 80
```

Site config file:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
   ServerName [name of the server]
   ServerAdmin [mail of the admin]

   RailsEnv staging
   DocumentRoot /var/rails/appname/current/public

   PassengerHighPerformance on

   <Directory /var/rails/appname/current/public>
      AllowOverride all
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache log:

```
[Fri Apr 15 08:58:21.432156 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5307] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Apr 15 08:58:21.432368 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5307] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Fri Apr 15 08:58:21.432420 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5307] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Fri Apr 15 08:58:21.432457 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5307] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Fri Apr 15 08:58:21.432510 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5307] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Apr 15 08:58:21.438925 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5307:tid 140495461242752] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

Line 74 of apache2.conf is a default value that I haven't changed:

```
#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
```

**EDIT**
Solved the problem detailed in Apache log using this link below:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/452042/why-is-my-apache-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04

Alas, the problem of connection persists

Comment: Seems like you need to configure those variables first, line 74 seems to be complaining about undefined ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} variable

Comment: check http://askubuntu.com/questions/452042/why-is-my-apache-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Ok, this seems to clear the log, but the error persists.